# Does the System Configuration framework provide class(s) to view data packet?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, network-programming

I have been looking at the [System Configuration Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html) to find out if it can be used to view packet data being sent from a specific network adapter. I see that there are classes which provide high level statistics such as: BytesIn, BytesOut. But I want to capture/monitor the actual data packets. Specifically TCP/IP packets. I'm not familiar with this framework yet. Can this be used to do this? If not can anyone suggest a library or native interface which can?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you need to pick up the packets that are coming to/from the wire, you want to use `bpf`, the Berkeley Packet Filter (`man bpf`).  It's very capable, and very low level, so don't expect an objective-c interface for it.  There may be some higher-level frameworks out there, although I don't recall any for Objective-C off the top of my head.

However, there are definitely plenty of unix applications that use `bpf` and which you could take a look at.  I believe the venerable [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org), which is included on OS X, uses bpf.

Of course, for monitoring packets, you'll need root privileges, so if you want to do this in an app, you'll need to address raising the security level to handle this.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have something working written in C. You were right couldn't find anything higher level. I ended up going with libpcap which, I believe, is just tcpdump's static lib. Thanks!